# Botão para excluir eventos FullCalendar - Celke

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap, netbeans, fullcalendar

No código abaixo, quando eu clico em "Excluir evento" dá um erro de que é preciso selecionar o evento(ID do evento).

[image: Desc]

**Código onde os eventos são carregados:**

```
eventClick: function(event) {

                    $('#visualizar #id').text(event.id);
                    $('#visualizar #id').val(event.id);
                    $('#visualizar #title').text(event.title);
                    $('#visualizar #title').val(event.title);
                    $('#visualizar #start').text(event.start.format('DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss'));
                    $('#visualizar #start').val(event.start.format('DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss'));
                    $('#visualizar #end').text(event.end.format('DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss'));
                    $('#visualizar #end').val(event.end.format('DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss'));
                    $('#visualizar #color').val(event.color);
                    $('#visualizar').modal('show');
                    return false;

                },
```

**Botão:**

`<a class="btn btn-danger" type="button" href="deletar_evento.php">Excluir evento</a>`

**deletar_evento.php:**

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once("conexao.php");
$id = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'id', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
if(!empty($id)){
    $result_events = "DELETE FROM events WHERE id='$id'";
    $resultado_events = mysqli_query($conn, $result_usuario);
    if(mysqli_affected_rows($conn)){
        $_SESSION['msg'] = "<div class='alert alert-success' role='alert'>Evento excluído com sucesso!<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-label='Close'><span aria-hidden='true'>&times;</span></button></div>";
        header("Location: index.php");
    }else{

        $_SESSION['msg'] = "<div class='alert alert-danger' role='alert'>Erro ao excluír evento!<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-label='Close'><span aria-hidden='true'>&times;</span></button></div>";
        header("Location: index.php");
    }
}else{  
    $_SESSION['msg'] = "<div class='alert alert-danger' role='alert'>É necessário selecionar um evento!<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-label='Close'><span aria-hidden='true'>&times;</span></button></div>";
    header("Location: index.php");
}
```

**Site do Celke: https://celke.com.br/artigo/como-editar-um-evento-no-fullcalendar-com-janela-modal-do-bootstrap**

Comment: Você não está passando o ID na URL, o correto é `<a href="deletar_inscricao.php?id=<SEU-ID>"><button class="btn btn-danger">Excluir
evento</button></a>`

Comment: Como assim meu ID? sou burro...

Comment: O `<SEU-ID>` é o *ID* do evento que você deseja excluir, por exemplo `deletar_inscricao.php?id=3`

Comment: Mas, por exemplo, o usuário(eu) iria abrir o evento para editar. Não tem como ele ler o id sozinho?                                                                    Posta sua resposta pra eu avaliar ela como útil!

Comment: Se você não passar o parâmetro ID na URL, o PHP não conseguirá identificar o evento que o usuário quer remover.

Comment: Ah... deixa pra lá. Mas valeu mesmo cara! tu me ajudou muito deu uma esclarecida e também agora pelo menos ele está excluindo, o que antes não fazia...

Answer (score 1):

Acho que é preciso colocar os pontinhos pra ele juntar a string com a variável:

Disso:

```
$result_events = "DELETE FROM events WHERE id='$id'";
```

Para isso:

```
$result_events = "DELETE FROM events WHERE id='".$id."'";
```

Se não for poste o erro por favor...

Comment: O erro é só que ele não identifica o ID do evento sozinho, você tem que declarar antes de apagar no código aí ele funciona:                 `<a href="deletar_inscricao.php?id=1(EXEMPLO)><button type="button" class="btn btn-delet btn-danger">Apagar</button></a> `

Answer (score 0):

Se você estiver familiar com Jquery, não sei bem como você tem o código mas pode tentar assim

A tag `<a>` deverá ter um `id`, tipo assim: `<a href="deletar_inscricao.php" id="tag_a_alterar">`

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
  eventClick: function(event) {
     $("#tag_a_alterar").attr("href", "deletar_inscricao.php?id="+calEvent.id);
  }
});
```

Assim, sempre que carregar num evento, irá mudar o `href` para o que deseja apagar.

Para definir o `id` de um evento, irá de ter de acrescentar um campo extra ao mostrar esse evento.

Se for como estou a pensar, deve ser assim que está o código, basta só acrescentar um `id`

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
  events: [
    {
      title  : 'event1',
      start  : '2010-01-01'
      id: '1'
    },
    {
      title  : 'event2',
      start  : '2010-01-05',
      end    : '2010-01-07'
      id: '2'
    }
  ]
});
```

Comment: Os eventos são carregados a partir do banco de dados :/, não tem o `title  : 'event1',
      start  : '2010-01-01'
      id: '1'`

Comment: Mas mostre onde eles são carregados

Comment: No cabeçalho do código têm `<?php
session_start();
include_once("conexao.php");
$result_events = "SELECT id, title, obs, local, start, end FROM events";
$resultado_events = mysqli_query($conn, $result_events);
?>`

Comment: Tentei me inspirar na página de editar evento, na hora de chamar o evento, porém do mesmo jeito dá esse erro de selecionar o Evento(ID). Achei que a página de editar já iria chamar o ID direto, pois ela edita o evento.

Comment: Ele deverá ter uma parte onde lista os eventos, procure bem onde declara a o `script` do `FullCalendar`

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1iRNDw80Gpcuw-Otz01qC8vCrfs33RS2c/view

Comment: @AndréLira Ele já está a definir um `id` lá, mesmo depois do `while($row_events = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado_events)){`. Tente usar a forma que eu lhe falei e mostre caso ocorra algum erro

Comment: Onde eu coloco o: `$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
  eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
     $("#tag_a_alterar").attr("href", "deletar_inscricao.php?id="+calEvent.id);
  }
});` ?

Comment: No seu código você já tem um `eventClick` por isso só precisa de pôr `$("#tag_a_alterar").attr("href", "deletar_inscricao.php?id="+event.id);` dentro, mas lembresse que primeiro tem de adicionar um `id` ao botão de apagar e substituir o `#tag_a_alterar` pelo nome que deseja.

Comment: Não tem como ele ler o evento que eu tô puxando sozinho? porque eu quero adicionar o botão na parte do "Editar" onde já deve ser feita uma verificação de ID do evento puxado.

Comment: @AndréLira Com esse código ele já lê o evento sozinho e altera consoante o que você carregar

Comment: Eventos desaparecem quando adicionado: `$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
  eventClick: function(event) {
     $("#tag_a_alterar").attr("href", "deletar_inscricao.php?id="+calEvent.id);
  }
}); `

Comment: O que complica é que o calendário "puxa" os eventos com `eventClick: function (event) {
                        $('#visualizar #id').text(event.id);
                        $('#visualizar #id').val(event.id);                                  
                        return false;
                    },`                                                                                        Teria que achar um jeito de meio que juntar essa parte com o botão.

Comment: @AndréLira Adicione um `id` ao botão, e depois basta usar o código que disse.